# Regex trying to get a match in php

Tags: php, regex

Im trying to make a regex pattern for strings that contain `[[Title#Night|Anchor]]` or just `[[Title|Anchor]]` and extract `Title` and `Anchor`. Basically two variables, first part between `[[ and |` and second part between `| and ]]`, no matter what type of characters are inside (excluding \n, \r).

I had tried writing different patterns and none worked like I wanted. The code can be [seen here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/2EF) with a sample content that I need to apply to.

```
\[\[(.*?)|(.*?)\]\]
```

Comment: `/\[\[([^\r\n|]*?)\|([^\r\n|]*?)\]\]/`, and probably don't use that site: I've found it quite broken. The mean issue was you forgot to escape the `|`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may this help you:

```
$str = ' [[Title#Night|Anchor]] ';
preg_match('/\[\[([\s\S]*?)\]\]/',$str,$match);
print_r(explode('|',$match[1]));
```

update:

```
preg_match('/\[\[([\s\S]*?)\|([\s\S]*?)\]\]/',$str,$match);
print_r($match);
```

update 2:

```
preg_match('/\[\[(.*?)\|(.*?)\]\]/',$str,$match);
print_r($match);
```

update 3:

```
preg_match('/\[\[([^|\n\r]*)\|([^\]\n\r]*)\]\]/',$str,$match);
print_r($match);
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea, I was thinking of using a solution just with regex but this might work.

Comment: Since the string inside square brackets can't contain newlines, you can replace `[\s\S]*?` by `.*?`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte thx~  i took excluding as including before.orz

Comment: As the first string inside the square brackets end with the first pipe, you can replace `(.*?)` with `[^|]*` that should be faster (avoiding non-greedy matches). The second part can be done similarly with `[^\]]*` (anything that is not an ending square bracket)

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for alphanumeric entries, depends what you want Title or Anchor to contain.

```
\[\[([a-zA-Z0-9#]*)\|([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\]\]
```

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. I also think you have some errors in that pattern, I fixed the errors and got to this \[\[([a-zA-Z0-9#]+)\|([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\]\] but works only for one match that has # in it. You can try the pattern in the link I provided in my question.